# Not Displaying values in Listview

Tags: android, mysql, listview, http-post

I am trying to fatch value from datbase and display all the values in listview.
My code is:

```
try
    {           
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/meetingschedular/viewdetail.php?mdate="+viewdate.getText().toString());
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Convert response to string
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();                 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //END Convert response to string

            try
            {               
                JSONArray jArray =  new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                {   
                    JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    JSONObject json_data = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);                     
                    String at= json_data.getString("attendees"); 
                    String at1=json_data.getString("title");                    
                    String at2=json_data.getString("mtime");
                    String at3=json_data.getString("venue");
                    s.append(j+"Attendees:"+at);
                    s.append("\nTitle:"+at1);
                    s.append("\nTime:"+at2);
                    s1.append("\nVenue:"+at3);

                    r.add(s.toString());
                    //r.add(s1.toString());
                    j++;
                }

                l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, r));

            }

            catch(Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sorry No Meeting Details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

But when I am displaying the List view I am getting only one row from Database and its getting displayed twice while the second row of database is not getting displayed.

[image: like this]

PLs hlp me.. :(

Here is my Xml File

```
'<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/prle"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Meetdetail1Activity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/Grey"
    android:text="@string/homelinkpropose"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/Grey"
    android:text="@string/logoutproposemeet"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/meetdetaill"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/meetdettextsize" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/viewdate" />

<ListView
    style="@style/dividedListStyle"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp">

 </ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/viewname"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sixtn" />
```

Comment: Try to declare StringBuffer s inside for loop and test once...

Comment: It seems that You get the whole value from database into one visible String, was this Your purpose? The picture above looks like Your view where You want to show the information cuts the string because it is to small. Could You post your xml from listView item?

Comment: you are using simple_expandable_list_item_1, sure you dont want a normal simple_list_item_1 @priya89

Comment: How can i segregate the information and display it in each row of list view? @Opiatefuchs

Comment: first You should make a custom adapter and a list item xml. The list item xml is a layout only for every row in a listView, not the whole xml from the main layout like You added. For a good example, read this tutorial: http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Comment: what is j inside Your for loop? Why do You j++ at the end? Is r an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

where you declare s and r variable?

you must declare ArrayList variable in before for loop

check your xml list view you may give fixed size for that. change to wrap or fill parent

Answer (score 0):

i think your JSON-String-handling has some issues, try:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("atendees");

for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

ofc you have to handle this for the other json-tables aswell!